# Java maven selenium not working in a docker container

Tags: java, docker, selenium, maven, automated-tests

I am new with docker containers and testing and have no idea how to solve this, been having a hard time these days. My tests are working in windows but when I create the docker container, my tests are not working, so I want to run a maven project in a docker container. The thing is I have been solving a lot of errors but still lots of them.
Before I start, I use openstax/selenium-chrome image with java, maven,chromedriver already installed and JAVA_HOME already set. Java version is 17 on the container and the project has 1.8.

> Chromedriver version is ChromeDriver 88.0.4324.96
>
> Google-chrome version is Google Chrome 88.0.4324.96

1- I create the docker container from the image I already created with everything installed passing the maven project inside.

```
docker run -it -d -v C:\Users\user\Projects\TestAutomation:/app --name=testsel maven-selenium/selenium
```

2- I enter with the user

```
docker exec -it testsel /bin/bash
```

3- I switch to the directory that I have the mvn project

4- I execute the maven project with mvn test
5- this is my pom.xml

```
 <build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>17</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
    <configuration>
      <includes>
        <include>org/nameofproject/tests/Test.java</include>
      </includes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

6- Setting chrome options for linux

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
        options.addArguments("--proxy-server='direct://'");
        options.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/usr/bin/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

7- The errors I am getting
[image]

[image]

[image]

and at the end another error

```
 Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: username (tried for 60 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)(..)
```

I am using explicit wait in locating the elements

```
 wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(60));

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("username"))).sendKeys(Const.user);
```

but still not working.

Edit:
This is the complete error at the end of test execution.
[image]
It fails at CBLogin because it's not finding the username element.

Comment: Is your source code (i.e. tests) on github, so that I can pull and try it locally?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have it on GitHub. Maybe you could solve it this way. On local works fine but when I change it to Linux doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try increasing the windows size, as it might not be in the viewport , I was facing the same Issue and was able to solve it

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
        chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1580,1280");
```

You could also try scrolling to element first if you think its not visible in viewport using actions class or JavascriptExecutor

Using Actions Class

```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("my-id"));
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.moveToElement(element);
    actions.perform();
```

Using JavascriptExecutor

```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id_of_element"));
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

Comment: I just tried @nika65 answer, but still not working. I just edited the post, I added a new image about the error. My question is:  In some cases I saw people open ports when running the container, is it needed 100% to open the ports or something?

Comment: Forgot this, I don't need to scroll because it's a login page, and that is a textbox that is trying to find.